# How to convert this form in zend form

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I've this HTML form, I need to write it in zend form.
I tried but failed

```
< form id="form" method="post" class="form">
<fieldset>
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="title"><img src="images/icons/dark/list.png" alt="" class="titleIcon" /><h6>Add new section</h6></div>
        <div class="formRow">
            <label>Section name:</label>
            <div class="formRight">
                <input type="text" name="cat_name" id="cat_name" value="" />
                <input name="art_author" id="art_author" type="hidden" value="admin" />
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="formSubmit">
            <input type="submit" value="Add" class="redB" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="brownB" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Can any body help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html

Second step http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.html

And do not make copy paste. Try to make your zend_form work using Zend Manual.

Good luck!